# Transparent window for sending message in android

Tags: android, android-intent, message, transparent, onclicklistener

I have an activity which is having a webview and a set of buttons. I am using a timer to request focus to these buttons.But for clicking on them I want that there should be a transparent window having nothing except a layout upon clicking it notifies activity window that a click was registered and it calls getCurrentFocus().performClick() and I want this to happen again and again means all clicks must be gone through transparent window . So in my main activity I have done this for calling transparent activity

```
Intent trans = new Intent("web.browser.gk.TransparentActivity");
        startActivityForResult(trans,REQUEST_TRANSPARENT);
```

and in onActivity result I have done this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){ 
            switch(requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_TRANSPARENT:
                Toast.makeText(this, "TRANSPARENT Acitivity clicked ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(flag)
                {
                    numpad.getCurrentFocus().performClick();
                }
                else
                {
                getCurrentFocus().performClick();
                }
                        break;

            case REQUEST_CODE:

            if (data.hasExtra("websearch")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getExtras().getString("websearch"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String i =  data.getExtras().getString("websearch");
                webview.loadUrl(i);

            }
            break;
        }
        }

        Intent trans = new Intent("web.browser.gk.TransparentActivity");
        startActivityForResult(trans,REQUEST_TRANSPARENT);


    }
```

Now the problem is that in my code I am calling webview.loadUrl(i) but it does not load current url .It loads that url only after clicking on transparent window . Any suggestion how to handle this. Is there any other way of implementing this transparent window feature

Answer (score 0):

Only one activity can be running at a time, so if you put up a transparent activity then the activity behind it is going to be paused.  You could use a View or a Fragment, but actually if all you are trying to do is detect clicks then probably the best way to handle this is to simply override dispatchTouchEvent.

```java
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
{
    if(me.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) // user touched the screen
        doSomething();
    // pass the event on to the view that's supposed to get it
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

Comment: Please user1853479 extend your answer. Some code maybe helpful.